# What does CF in CFnumber,CFstring etc in xcode application mean?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-foundation

I have minimum exposure to Xcode and i/o kit. I came across terms like CFString, CFNumber etc. Whether this CF have any particular meaning like these strings and numbers inherited from C or like C string or numbers. I just want to know what CF refers to.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*CFString*, *CFNumber* etc., are declared in **Core Foundation Framework**, and this makes it obvious that *CF* is the abbreviation of *Core Foundation*. We do create objects of those *CF types* like ***CF[Type]Ref***,

```
CFStringRef str;
```

Note that here we not using `*`, though *CFStringRef* is a *reference type*. Most of this CFTypes are ***"toll-free bridged”*** with their Core Foundation counter parts. Which means they can be used interchangeably. For example, ***CFStringRef*** is *"toll-free bridged”* with its counter part ***NSString***, and both the following lines are completely valid.

```
CFStringRef str = (CFStringRef)aNSStringObject; // Valid
NSString *str = (NSString *)aCFStringRefObject; // Valid
```

Answer (score 4):

It stands for [Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/corefoundation/), which is Apple's C-based API that:

> provides the fundamental data types and essential services that
>   underlie both the Cocoa and Carbon environments on Mac OS X.